# I had been going to school vs I had gone to school

Tags: tense

I have looked up the difference of "I had been going" and "I had gone" but I still don't understand the difference of two and when to use which.

So what is the difference and in what situation would you use each?

Also with "I will have been going to school" and "I will have gone to school"

Answer (score 2):

PAST PER CONT: I had been going to school. Describes an action in the past that started before another moment in the past, and had not finished by that moment: When I met your sister, I had been going to school for two years.

PAST PER: I had gone to school. Describes an action in the past that happened and finished before another moment in the past: They came to visit me but I had gone to school, so we didn't meet.